# update image with jquery based on multiple radio button inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An image is being rendered based on multiple attributes.
The name of the image reflects attribute values (for names a, b, & c).

```
<div>  
  <img src="112_small.jpg" data-zoom-image="112_big.jpg" id="rendered_choice">  
</div>    
<div>  
  <h6>9</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="a_1" name="a" value="1" checked="checked" />  
  <input type="radio" id="a_2" name="a" value="2" />  
  <input type="radio" id="a_3" name="a" value="3" />  
</div>  
<div>  
  <h6>10</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="b_1" name="b" value="1" checked="checked" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_2" name="b" value="2" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_3" name="b" value="3" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_4" name="b" value="4" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_5" name="b" value="5" />  
</div>  
<div>  
  <h6>11</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="c_1" name="c" value="1" />  
  <input type="radio" id="c_2" name="c" value="2" checked="checked" />  
</div>
```

when a user clicks a radio button (say b_4), the checked input element needs to change and a new image needs to render as

```
<img src="142_small.jpg" data-zoom-image="142_big.jpg" id="rendered_choice">
```

How can this be accomplished with jQuery, where the file name takes into account all other checked values in addition to the user inputted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `value` of each checked checkbox, in order, after making an array with [`$.makeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/):

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  const num = $.makeArray($("input:checked")).map(({ value }) => value).join("");
  $("#rendered_choice").attr("src", num + "_small.jpg").data("zoom-image", num + "_big.jpg");
});
```

Comment: given there is a `src` and `data-zoom-image` that need to be populated, there ought to be an intermediary step to just extract the array as a variable, then use that, yes?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add that @Jerome.

Comment: Edited @Jerome, any better?

Comment: succinct and refactored.  Very satisfactory.

Comment: No problem whatsoever @Jerome, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of each checked checkbox and change the img src when input checked change.

Demo:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  var index = $("input[name=a]:checked").val() + $("input[name=b]:checked").val() + $("input[name=c]:checked").val();
  $("#rendered_choice").attr("src", index + "_small.jpg");
  $("#rendered_choice").attr("data-zoom-image", index + "_big.jpg");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>  
  <img src="112_small.jpg" data-zoom-image="112_big.jpg" id="rendered_choice">  
</div>    
<div>  
  <h6>9</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="a_1" name="a" value="1" checked="checked" />  
  <input type="radio" id="a_2" name="a" value="2" />  
  <input type="radio" id="a_3" name="a" value="3" />  
</div>  
<div>  
  <h6>10</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="b_1" name="b" value="1" checked="checked" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_2" name="b" value="2" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_3" name="b" value="3" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_4" name="b" value="4" />  
  <input type="radio" id="b_5" name="b" value="5" />  
</div>  
<div>  
  <h6>11</h6>  
  <input type="radio" id="c_1" name="c" value="1" />  
  <input type="radio" id="c_2" name="c" value="2" checked="checked" />  
</div>
```